# All circular geodesics of Schwarzschild interior solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, geodesics

I examine parametric stability of interior Schwarzschild solution by analyzing its circular geodesics. The picture below shows the result of solving corresponding geodesics equation ([Is black hole event horizon a transcendent tachyon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757634/281096)). Depending on combination of the reduced Schwarzschild and geodesics curvature radii, $\alpha\equiv r_S/R$ and $r_0\equiv r_0/R$, there are four distinct regions divided by three curves in the diagram.

My question is how to interpret the region $\text{IV}$? It represents the spacetime "behind" the hyperspace defined by the equation $g_{00}(r,\alpha)=0$, however there are no circular geodesics there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to make of your "$\rm r_0=\frac{r_0}{R}$", but the radius of the sphere must be larger than $\rm \frac{9}{8} r_s$. If it's smaller the interior Schwarzschild solution isn't valid since homogenous and static density is not possible with smaller spheres (that would require imaginary pressure), so if your $\rm R$ is the sphere's radius then your $\alpha$ needs to be smaller than $\frac{8}{9}=0.\dot{8}$, everything above is unphysical.

Comment: The spacetime diagrams for a radial gravity tunnel are [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/schwarzschild.interior.freifalldiagramme.html#13a) by the way, but the focus there is on lightlike and timelike paths so I'll add that only as a comment.

Comment: $r_0$ is made dimensionless. My comment to your answer comes tomorrow. Great app by the way.

Comment: Please look in the paper [Surface Tension and Negative Pressure Interior of a Non-Singular Black Hole](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.03806) page 4. Above Buchdahl limit the interior solution is still static but with negative (not imaginary) pressure. While the pressure gradient is negative too the "star" is still in equilibrium.

Comment: However, the explanation with the so-called gravastar does not convince me too - see [Stable gravastars - an alternative to black holes?](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0310107v2) by Matt Visser and  David L. Wiltshire.

Comment: Yukterez It seems to me that your app simulates numerically what Edward Parker calculated analytically, see [Relativistic train](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04026). Do you know that paper?